# How to destructure multiple query results in sequence?

Tags: node.js, destructuring, pg-query

I want to use the same pattern for destructuring query results, but seems I cannot. In the following code:

```
var {rows} = await client.query("SELECT id FROM mytable;");
var Id = rows[0].id; //destructured here as expected
```

if I then follow that with:

```
rows = await client.query('SELECT max(id) as id FROM table2;');
```

The only way I can access the value is like this:

```
rows.rows[0].id;
```

Shouldn't I be able to access as in the first instance, like this?

```
rows[0].id;
```

Do I need to somehow reset `{rows}`?

Very new to JS so finding my way.

Comment: client.query returns you an object with a property 'rows.' Assigning the variable you've created by destructuring to the return value of client.query will result in rows.rows.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/KosherHotBooleanalgebra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to restructure the variable. Simply assign to `rows` will just get the full response object assigned to the variable, as you've seen.

Destructuring to the same variable has a couple gotchas because you can't do this:

```
let {rows} = await client.query("SELECT id FROM mytable;");
// Error: unexpected token without declaration
{rows} = await client.query('SELECT max(id) as id FROM table2;');
// Error: Identifier 'rows' has already been declared
let {rows} = await client.query('SELECT max(id) as id FROM table2;');
```

You can declare `var` multiple times:

```
var {rows} = await client.query("SELECT id FROM mytable;");
// no problemo
var {rows} = await client.query('SELECT max(id) as id FROM table2;');
```

If you want to declare with `let` then you need to do something like:

```
let {rows} = await client.query("SELECT id FROM mytable;");
// this works too…
({rows} = await client.query('SELECT max(id) as id FROM table2;'));
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!